# How to upgrade to Python 3.5 in a Docker container that has already installed Python 3.4? (I'm running Docker containers on Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: docker, numpy, pip, python-3.5, ubuntu-20.04

I am using **Docker on Ubuntu 20.04**. A Docker container has already Python 3.4.2 installed on it.
Now, I'm gonna **upgrade it to Python 3.5** or later. I didn't find anything useful on the web to do that. Would be thankful if anyone lends my hands.

I need that to install **numpy** on the Docker container. I've already upgraded the **pip** and **setuptools** for the Python 3.4.2, but when I run:

**pip3 install numpy**

it returns that a Python 3.5 or later required.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Based on how you have created your image (`Dockerfile` or `docker-compose`), you can update your image.

Comment: You can find my Docker image in the link below. It's Debian-based.           https://hub.docker.com/r/ucmercedandeslab/tinyos_debian

Comment: OK, that's a simple question: how do you run your image? Do you have `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose`?

Comment: Using this: docker run -ti <image_name>.      I don't know what you mean by docker-compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Raedwald mentioned, you can use your [ucmercedandeslab/tinyos_debian](https://hub.docker.com/r/ucmercedandeslab/tinyos_debian) image as the base image and create a new docker image with specified version of python installed. To do this you need to do the following:

**Step 1**: Create a Dockerfile. You can use the file specified [here](https://gist.github.com/dfee/388c3f270fdfc4f31aba906770f93137). This Dockerfile uses the [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) library to manage python versions. All you need to do is change the first line from

`FROM debian:stable` to `FROM ucmercedandeslab/tinyos_debian:latest`

Change the python arg (`ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.2`) to whatever version you prefer. By default it's Python 3.6.2

**Step 2**: Build docker image via the `docker build` command

You now have a docker image that has python 3.6.2 as the default python.

Comment: I mean where to create Dockerfile and where to store that? Should it be inside the base image? And how and where to build docker image?

Comment: Make an empty directory and copy the file I linked as it is into it.   Then change line 1 as I mentioned in step 1. To build the docker image, from the terminal navigate to the directory you've created and run `docker build .`

Comment: It should be ucmercedandeslab/tinyos_debian:latest, not stable. Check step 1.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks! Now next step would be getting into the image "ucmercedandeslab/tinyos_debian" again and check for Python 3.6, is that right?

Comment: Now, how to find the new image that has an updated Python on it? If it is the same base image, I don't see any updated Python in that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The new Python is in the new docker image you’ve built. At the end of the build process you’ll see “Successfully built <image id>”. That’s the one that has the new Python.

Comment: Thank yo so much! The issue is now fixed.

Comment: If this solved your issue, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: do you know any Dockerfile to upgrade to Python 3.7 or higher? I tried that Dockerfile you sent me and applied my desired Python versions but it doesn't work. @ashnair1

Comment: Change the `ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.2` line in the Dockerfile to whatever Python version you want

Comment: Yes, I did it but it returns me an error. Let me know how to share the error with you.

Comment: See [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73674620/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-an-existing-docker-container?noredirect=1#comment130101092_73674620) this error I get once I change it to ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.2 and build it @ashnair1

Answer (score 1):

Change the base image in the Dockerfile, tto use the new Python version, then rebuild the image.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that? I am super new in that.

Comment: You can find my Docker image in the link below. It's Debian-based.           https://hub.docker.com/r/ucmercedandeslab/tinyos_debian