# How to install Tensorflow on an existing Docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am using **Docker on Ubuntu 20.04**. The Docker container has already **Python 3.6.2** installed on it. Now, I want to install **Tensorflow** on that particular container (i.e. I **don't** want to pull **Tensorflow image**, I need to keep my existing container and install Tensorflow on that). I didn't find anything useful on the web. Would be thankful if anyone lends me some hand.

Also, to handle Tensorflow installations, I've tried upgrading Python on that container through **Dockerfile** [here](https://gist.github.com/dfee/388c3f270fdfc4f31aba906770f93137) (after I modify it based on what I desire). After I build it, this output comes up:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As a general rule, you don't install things in existing containers; those changes will be lost as soon as the container exits and you'll have to repeat your installation work.  The Dockerfile approach you describe sounds better, what have you done so far and what produces the error message you show?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the answer! I edited the question to reflect what were you looking for.

Comment: Might be a network issue. Check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899009/sudo-apt-update-always-giving-clearsigned-file-isnt-valid-got-nosplit-does)